# Compare Dates in Slick 3.1.1

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I am trying to write a simple filter query using slick 3.1. I was successfully able to write for Integer Types which get converted to Rep[Integer]. But how to achieve comparison for java.util.Date which get converted to Rep[Date] inside filter query?

```
val compareWithDate = new GregorianCalendar(2014, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 11).getTime()  // for example
val persons = TableQuery[Persons]
dbConfig.db.run(persons.filter(???))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `slick-joda-mapper` https://github.com/tototoshi/slick-joda-mapper and convert your types to Rep[DateTime] which is easily used in filters

it's very simple to use, just import what joda support you need and you can use these type of objects:

> DateTime, Instant, LocalDateTime, LocalDate, LocalTime, DateTimeZone

on your table you will have something like this:

```
def createdDt = column[DateTime]("created_dt")
```

take a look here for some examples: https://github.com/tototoshi/slick-joda-mapper/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/github/tototoshi/slick/JodaSupportSpec.scala#L191